# Flory Huggins Theory

Tags: polymers

For an ideal chain, Flory Huggins theory gives us a distribution which is like a Gaussian.

$$P(l, r) \sim \left(\frac{3}{2 \pi l^2}\right)^{3/2} e^{\frac{-3 r^2}{2 l^2}}$$

where, $l$ is the monomer to monomer distance(also known as Kuhn length) and $R$ is the size of the monomer

This is great but what are the approximation away from an ideal chain polymer? I want to understand how one can go beyond Flory Huggins Theory.

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions made in the [Flory-Huggins theory](http://aerosolschool.web.psi.ch/gothenburg_2008/Group_reviews/FloryHugginsTheory.pdf) are

- Quasi-solid lattice in the liquid
- Inter-changeability of segments (not necessarily the same as the polymer structure
  units) of polymer and solvent molecules in the lattice
- Independence of lattice constants on composition (artificial)
- Polymer molecules are of same size
- Average concentration of polymer segments in cells adjacent to cells unoccupied
  by the polymeric solute is taken to be equal to the overall average concentration
- The expected number of available positions for each successive segment is
  overestimated in the formulation as the formula includes double counting of
  segments, separated by 2 or more segments in the same chain, that will fall on the
  same position twice

In particular the assumption that polymer molecules are of the same size is a very unrealistic one, which was later removed in the [Flory-Krigbaum theory](http://books.google.nl/books?id=OSAaRwBXGuEC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=assumptions%20Flory-Krigbaum&source=bl&ots=wUMrb_5mzq&sig=6WqCD6fgk1y9o6FyF6pDPKq5uVg&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=oRRAU9yqBYvKOY-ygZgN&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=assumptions%20Flory-Krigbaum&f=false)